# Add a COMMA after a CURLY Brace For JSON Format

Tags: json, python-3.x

Hello there i am working on a dataset but its not formatted correctly. It's missing its Square brackets and comma after every object
Example:

```
{"is_sarcastic": 1, "headline": "thirtysomething scientists unveil doomsday clock of hair loss", "article_link": "something"}
{"is_sarcastic": 0, "headline": "dem rep. totally nails why congress is falling short on gender, racial equality", "article_link": "somethingelse"}
```

I want to format it such that it turns to this:

```
[{"is_sarcastic": 1, "headline": "thirtysomething scientists unveil doomsday clock of hair loss", "article_link": "something"},
{"is_sarcastic": 0, "headline": "dem rep. totally nails why congress is falling short on gender, racial equality", "article_link": "somethingelse"}]
```

I am using Python 3.x to achieve this task.

Comment: it each of these is on its own line you can simply do: `'[' + ','.join(mydata.split('\n')) + ']'`

Comment: do i load it as a normal text file in python and then after processing save it back as a json file?

Answer (score 4):

you can run the following python script, it'll output a file containing the output you desire.

```
import json

dataJson = []

with open('data.json') as f:
    for jsonObj in f:
        dataDict = json.loads(jsonObj)
        dataJson.append(dataDict)

#print (dataJson)        
with open('data2.json', 'w') as jsonfile:
    json.dump(dataJson, jsonfile)
```

where data.json is the name of the file containing the dataset